# How to redirect URL with HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I need redirect www.foo.com and foo.com to www.bar.com in haproxy, this is my configuration:

```
frontend  http-in
    bind *:80

    acl bar.com hdr(host) -i www.bar.com
    ...
    use_backend     bar.com_cluster if bar.com
    ... 
    redirect prefix http://foo.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.bar.com }
    redirect prefix http://www.foo.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.bar.com }
    ...

backend bar.com_cluster
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server bar 10.0.0.1:80 check
```

I have tried with `redirect prefix` but don't work, any idea?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Change order of the hostname:

```
redirect prefix http://www.bar.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i foo.com }
redirect prefix http://www.bar.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.foo.com }
```

instead of

```
redirect prefix http://foo.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.bar.com }
redirect prefix http://www.foo.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i www.bar.com }
```

Comment: Would you know how to do this with pfSense HAProxy? I tried Expression: Custom acl with no success.