# haproxy redirect to new domain if string found in request but keep and send all URL parameters

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I want to do the following using haproxy:

if I get a request on domain 1 which includes a certain string (ie map1), I want to keep all that is after first / following the domain and redirect it all to domain 2. For example:

If I get https://sub1.domain1.gr/kjhkjhkh??efreerwer

I want to redirect to

https://sub2.domain2.gr/kjhkjhkh??efreerwer

Trying the following:

acl domain1_url hdr(host) sub1.domain1.gr
acl map1_uri capture.req.uri -m reg map1
http-request set-var(req.map1_uri) if domain1_url map1_uri
http-request set-path /%[var(req.map1_uri)]%[path] if { var(req.map1_uri) -m found }
http-request set-header Host sub2.domain2.gr if { var(req.map1_uri) -m found }

Is there something wrong with this logic?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem.

I used:
acl domain1_url hdr(host) sub1.domain1.gr 
acl map1_uri capture.req.uri -m reg map1
http-request redirect code 301 location http://sub2.domain2.gr%[capture.req.uri] if map1_uri

Read about it at http://patg.net/haproxy,apache/2017/08/04/haproxy/

Comment: Adding `http-request` at the beginning of the line helped to make redirect work after adding `%[capture.req.uri]`